# Mailjet API 401 error when sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailjet

im getting this error

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailjet_stmp
```

whenever I open the view where mailjet is supposed to send an email, I set it up usinf mailjet gem and the mailer initializer, i will add the controller and initializer as well as the route and actual view. Please if there is anything missing let me know so i can provide any extra info to yall.
routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  unrelated routes 

  post '/send_invoice', to: "invoices#new"

end
```

controller:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :current_biz
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    if !current_user
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    else
      @invoices = current_biz.invoices
    end
  end

  def new
    invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)
    build_invoice
    send_invoice(invoice)
  end

  def create
    build_invoice
    save_invoice or render :new
  end

  def update
    @invoice = Invoice.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
      redirect_to request.referrer
    else
      render request.referrer
    end
  end

  private

  def current_biz
    @biz = Business.find_by(id: params[:business_id])
  end

  def invoice_params
    invoice_params = params[:invoice]
    invoice_params ? invoice_params.permit(:title, :services, :payer_name, :payer_email, :paid, :price, :business_id, :biller_name,:business_name, :biller_email, :reference, :paypal_username) : {}
  end

  def build_invoice
    @invoice ||= invoice_scope.build
    @invoice.attributes = invoice_params
  end

  def save_invoice
    if @invoice.save
      redirect_to business_invoices_path(@biz)
    end
  end

  def invoice_scope
    @biz.invoices
  end

  def send_invoice(invoice, error = false)
    mail = Mailjet::Send.create(messages: [{
      'From'=> {
        'Email'=> 'my@email.com',
        'Name'=> 'my name'
      },
      'To'=> [
        {
          'Email'=> "#{invoice.payer_email}",
          'Name'=> "#{invoice.payer_name}"
        }
      ],
      'Subject'=> "Invoice from #{invoice.business_name}",
      'HTMLPart'=> template(invoice),
    }]
    )
    p mail.attributes['Messages']
  end

  def template(invoice)
    "
      <h3>Hey #{invoice.payer_name}!</h3>
      <p> #{invoice.business_name} has send you an invoice with the title: '#{invoice.title}' for a total of #{invoice.price}</p>

      <p>You can pay the outstanding bill with the link below:</p>
      <a href='https://www.paypal.me/#{invoice.paypal_username}/#{invoice.price}' target='_blank' rel='noopener'><button type='button'>Pay!</button></a>

      <p>If this button does not work, you can copy and paste this link in the browser:
      https://www.paypal.me/#{invoice.paypal_username}/#{invoice.price}<br>
      </p>
    "
  end

end
```

the initilizer:

```
Mailjet.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = ENV["MAILJET_PUBLIC"]
  config.secret_key = ENV["MAILJET_PRIVATE"]
  config.default_from = 'my@email.com'
  config.api_version = 'v3.1'
end
```

and the view:

```
<div class="w-50 m-auto m-top">
  <button onClick='addServices()'>Add Services</button>
  <%= form_for [@biz, @invoice], url: send_invoice_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :reference, value: reference_generator %>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :bill_title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :biller_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :biller_name, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :biller_email %>
    <%= f.text_field :biller_email, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :business_name %>
    <%= f.select(:business_name, user_businesses ,class: 'form-control', required: true) %>
  </div>

  <div class='row services-row'>
    <div class='col-8'>
      <%= f.label :services %>
      <%= f.text_field :services, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class='col-4'>
      <%= f.label :amount %>
      <%= f.number_field :price, class: 'form-control service-price', onblur: 'addValues()', placeholder: "$", required: true %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :payer_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :payer_name, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :payer_email %>
    <%= f.text_field :payer_email, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :paypal_username %>
    <%= f.text_field :paypal_username, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    <%= f.check_box :paid, { class: 'form-check-input' } %>
    <%= f.label :paid %>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    Total:
    <span class='total'>
    </span>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: should be `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailjet` 
 https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-gem#send-emails-with-actionmailer

Comment: hey @Alex still getting the same error when entering the view Mailjet::ApiError in InvoicesController#new

Comment: I suspect is an issue with the controller @Alex